inconsistent results in ggplot
I'm making two volcano plots using ggplot and the parameters in both of them are the same except for the legend. However, the font size of the legends is different between the two plots. How can I fix this?
Also, how can I get the blue labels to be on one side and the pink ones on the other side? And is there a way that the lines connecting the dots to the labels be more consistent?
ggplot(data =  resLFC, aes(x =  log2FoldChange, y =  -log10(padj), col = diffs, label = delabel)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-30,30), ylim =  c(-10,80)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1, 1), col = "blue", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 4, col =  "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue1", "gray", "deeppink1"),
                     labels = c("Downregulated", "Not significant", "Upregulated")) +
  labs(color = "test 2 vs test 1 
    in testtt testttt",
    x =  expression("log"\[2\]*"FC"), y =  expression("-log"\[10\]*"p-value")) +
  geom_label_repel(nudge_x = c(-30,30), nudge_y = c(-10,20),force = 100, 
                   max.iter = 200000, max.segment.length = 0.005, max.overlaps = 10000) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.15, 0.80), legend.key.height =  unit(0.3, "cm"), 
        legend.key.width =  unit(1, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20), axis.title.x =  element_text(size = 20), 
        axis.title.y =  element_text(size = 20), legend.text = element_text(size = 8))

ggplot(data =  resLFC, aes(x =  log2FoldChange, y =  -log10(padj), col = diffs, label = delabel)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-30,30), ylim =  c(-10,80)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1, 1), col = "blue", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 4, col =  "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue1", "gray", "deeppink1"),
                     labels = c("Downregulated", "Not significant", "Upregulated")) +
  labs(color = "test 2 vs test 1 
    in test test",
    x =  expression("log"\[2\]*"FC"), y =  expression("-log"\[10\]*"p-value")) +
  geom_label_repel(nudge_x = c(-30,30), nudge_y = c(-10,20),force = 100, 
                   max.iter = 200000, max.segment.length = 0.005, max.overlaps = 10000) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.15, 0.80), legend.key.height =  unit(0.3, "cm"), 
        legend.key.width =  unit(1, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20), axis.title.x =  element_text(size = 20), 
        axis.title.y =  element_text(size = 20), legend.text = element_text(size = 8))




It will be easier for people to give you relevant answers if you can make your question reproducible by including some sample data as code, e.g. by making a function to generate a bunch of fake data or by using the dput() function to make a "code recipe" for a subset of your data.

Font size consistency should be straightforward if you are plotting with code, e.g. with ggsave (or the camcorder package if you want to iterate size tweaks more easily). See https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/ for a discussion of how resolution and dimensions interact with font sizes.

I can't think of an easy way to get the blue and pink labels to stay cleanly on different sides. One way might be to make your plot be two facets, or use patchwork to combine two plots, so that ggrepel's default behavior would keep the labels constrained. The challenge would be to tweak the formatting to remove all the axis padding and margins between the plots so they look like one.

"And is there a way that the lines connecting the dots to the labels be more consistent?"  Can you say more about what this means to you? "consistent" by what measure: angle, length, regular pattern? I suspect you are asking for a custom approach that goes beyond the generalized approach ggrepel was made for.

Personally, I think it is not a great idea to try to label all the "significant" genes. Label a few that you think are most interesting (e.g. based on prior knowledge), the list the others in a table in the supplementary material. This many labels makes the plot way too busy, and it covers up the points, which is what a volcano plot is actually supposed to be showing. Once you have fewer labels, it will be much easier to place them appropriately.

If you do want all these labels, one way of having the two sets have  their own side, is by having two sets of geom_text_repel, one with color = "blue" and hjust = "right for the lefthand side x's, the other one witj color = "pink" and hjust = "right". It is also possible to set limits, see https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html#examples.
